# How to check every value in a clamped array

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

When I getImageData() from a canvas, I get an ImageData object, with a Data sub-object, which is a clamped array. I want to check if every pixel I get is white (and not transparent). In other words, I want to check if every value in the data object is equal to 255. The obvious code would be the following:

```
if (data.every(function(value) {return value == 255})) {
    //Do something
    }
```

But for some reason it won't work in clamped arrays, as the following minimal code shows:

```
var DATA = new Uint8ClampedArray(3);
//var DATA = new Array

DATA[0] = 255
DATA[1] = 255
DATA[2] = 255
DATA[3] = 255

alert(DATA.every(function(value) {return value == 255}))
```

Any solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend the prototype of `Uint8ClampedArray` with an `every()` function, which can be taken from the `Array` prototype; then your code will work fine.

```
Uint8ClampedArray.prototype.every = Array.prototype.every;
```

I guess this is the easiest way to do it, but note that it will break the `for ... in` loop (which shouldn't be used to iterate over arrays anyway...).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Array method via `.call()`:

```
alert([].every.call(DATA, function(v) { return v === 255; }));
```

It doesn't work the way you wrote it because there's no `.every()` on the Uint8ClampedArray prototype.